# Moving JLabel in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have tried to write the program in java in which a label containing an image is moving every second, but unfortunately the code is not running despite it contains zero error. Can anyone make out what is happening. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class what extends JFrame {
         private JPanel  panel;
         private Random r= new Random();
         private JLabel image;
         private Random s = new Random();


         public what (){
             super("Catch him!");
             panel = new JPanel();
             Icon b = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("img.JPG"));
             image = new JLabel(b);
             panel.add(image);
             add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
             panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

             panel.add(image);
        while(true){
                int x = s.nextInt(1000);
                 int y = s.nextInt(900);

                  try{
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                  }catch(Exception e){

             }

                 image.setBounds(x, y,200, 200);
          }




}
        public static void main(String[] args){
            what c = new what();
            c.setVisible(true);
            c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            c.setSize(1920,1080);


                }


}
```

Please, Can anyone help me.

Comment: What is the output you are getting ?

Comment: Nothing the program wont execute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're executing an infinite loop inside a single thread. When `new what();` is created, the loop starts and never ends. As such `c.setVisible(true);` is never reached.

You will need to create a separate thread for this loop to be run in. You could create the following class;

```
public class Infout implements Runnable{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel image;
    private Random s = new Random();

    public Infout(JFrame frame, JLabel image){
        this.frame = frame;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
           int x = s.nextInt(1000);
           int y = s.nextInt(900);

           try{ Thread.sleep(1000); }
           catch(InterruptedException e){ }
           image.setBounds(x, y, 200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

and then instantiate and run in your main method like so;

```
Infout inf = new Infout(c, image);
new Thread(inf).start();
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks so does starting that loop in an other thread solve this problem

Comment: It would yes. But you'll have to pass your `JLabel` instance into that new thread, as well as call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` each time the bounds are changed. I'll add up an example runnable you can use.

Comment: Thanks please add an example

Comment: When i have tried this code the program gets executed but the label is not moving

Comment: @namanjain - Are you calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the frame? I edited those calls into the code above a little while ago.

Comment: Can you please tell me why this is happening.I have read the code but it seems to be correct.

Comment: Yes i got it when i remove repaint and revalidate it works fine.Can you tell me why this happened

Comment: @namanjain - It works fine when you don't call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` but not when you do?

Comment: Yes but why is it so.Is it because we are just moving a label and not modifying it

Comment: @namanjain - Not sure, that does seem like very odd behavior. I'll remove that from the answer but I'll be honest I don't know why it's doing that.

Comment: `when i remove repaint and revalidate it works fine` - by default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout. When you invoke revalidate() the layout manager is invoked and the label is positioned at the start of the panel. When doing aninmation you should be using a "null layout", then you program is responsible for set the size/location of the component. Also you should be using a `Swing Timer` for animation.

Comment: @camickr - Thanks. Learn something new every day. Mystery solved.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to thread off the while(true) loop into a new thread so that the swing thread can paint and display the frame.